# Log4Net - AdoNetAppender for sqlite not inserting

Tags: c#, sqlite, log4net, adonetappender

I'm trying to implement a log4net with a sqlite db file, but when I log something nothing happens.

My configuration:

```
<log4net>
      <appender name="sqlite-appender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender"> 
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <connectionString name = "DbConn" value="Data Source=C:[FilePath]\DebugLog.db;Synchronous=Off " />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO debug (Date, Level, Logger, Message) VALUES (@Date, @Level, @Logger, @Message)" />
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
   </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="sqlite-appender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I put on true the debug flag in the config file and I get this thrace:

```
    log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.
Nombre del parámetro: index
   en System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   en System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
   en System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection.GetParameter(String parameterName)
   en System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Data.IDataParameterCollection.get_Item(String parameterName)
   en log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter.FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   en log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
   en log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.
Nombre del parámetro: index
   en System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   en System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
   en System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameterCollection.GetParameter(String parameterName)
   en System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Data.IDataParameterCollection.get_Item(String parameterName)
   en log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter.FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   en log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
   en log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
```

When I use FileAppender it works fine I dont know what happens

Comment: Are you using 1.2.14? There's a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-489) with the ADONetAppender in that version.

Comment: Yes Im usin that version, what version i shoud use? 1.2.13?

Comment: Yes, downgrade to that for now, until 1.2.15 comes out with the fix.

Comment: Thaks I downgrade to 1.2.13 and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using 1.2.14 version that has a known issue with the ADONetAppender.

So I just downgrade to 1.2.13 and it works fine.

First uninstall the version 1.2.14:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package log4net Uninstall-Package
```

Then install the previous version:

```
PM> Install-Package log4net -Version 2.0.3
```

Thanks to [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd) who give me the answer.

Comment: The newer version 1.2.15 is availabe. In its release notes it says ado.net issues are resolved.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it.